# validate duplicates fields in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that need to be validated on the server.

The array look like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "sku" => "8x0c"
    "price" => "30.00"
    "stock" => 5
    "option_1" => 2
    "option_2" => 5
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "sku" => "qsaz"
    "price" => "30.00"
    "stock" => 5
    "option_1" => 2
    "option_2" => 5
  ]
]
```

This array contains only 2 entries (it can contain multiple entries).

option_1, option_2 and option_3 are dynamic fields and need to be unique.

The array can have minimum one dynamic field (option_1) and maximum 3 fields (option_1, option_2 and option_3)

In this case in the first array

```
"option_1" => 2
"option_2" => 5
```

and in the second

```
"option_1" => 2
"option_2" => 5
```

are the same (i have two variations for a product that have the same color and size - and I don't want this).

How can I validate / check for duplicates for the selected options ?

Comment: Are the keys "option_1" and "option_2" always going to be present within each of the arrays?

Comment: Could there be any number of option keys you mean? option_1, option_2, option_3, option_55? or do you mean "only" option_1, option_2 and option_3 ?

Comment: @Aran it is going to be present at least one option (fron 1 to 3)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes only these keys (option_1, option_2 and option_3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two options keys in the items array are always going to be present, then the below function would allow you to validate the options being unique:

```php
function validateUniqueOptions(array $items): bool
{
    // Keep track the options we've seen before
    $optionsSeen = [];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Generate a unique key for this item combining its selection options
        $optionKey = $item['option_1'] . '_' . $item['option_2'];

        if (in_array($optionKey, $optionsSeen)) {
            // This item is a duplicate of another we've seen previously, validation failed
            return false;
        }

        $optionsSeen[] = $optionKey;
    }

    // No duplicates found, validation successful
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why does not this always return true? (optionsSeen array is empty and never set?) OP wanted at most three options to (at least one and max three options)

Comment: I'd missed setting the item into the seen array, now corrected above, thanks for spotting.

Comment: No problem. I thought it was kind of important :-)

Answer (score 0):

This function below could handle as many option you'd like and if there are three options and two options in the other it is unique as well.

```
function check_options_duplicate($arr) {
    $options_arr = ["","",""]; //Place for three options..
    foreach($arr as $topkey=>$toplevel) {
        foreach($toplevel as $key=>$item) {
            if (substr($key,0,7) == 'option_') {
                $options_arr[$topkey] .= $item . ",";
            }
        }
    }
    //If number of items in array are not the same when removing 
    //duplicate values with array_unique => it is a duplicate     
    if (count($options_arr) !== count(array_unique($options_arr))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$is_duplicate = check_options_duplicate($arr);
if ($is_duplicate) {
    echo 'is duplicate';
}
else {
    echo 'is not duplicate';
}
```

**Example:** If having the array `$arr`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 8x0c
            [price] => 30.00
            [stock] => 5
            [option_1] => 4
            [option_2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => qsaz
            [price] => 30.00
            [stock] => 5
            [option_1] => 4
            [option_2] => 33
        )

)
```

it would result in the `$options_arr array`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4,3,
    [1] => 4,33,
    [2] => 
)
```

If doing an `array_unique()` it would be the same:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4,3,
    [1] => 4,33,
    [2] => 
)
```

If it both options would be the same:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4,3,
    [1] => 4,3,
    [2] => 
)
```

and you're doing an `unique_array()` it would only contain two items instead of 3.
Therefore it's a duplicate when you compare original `$options_arr` with unique `$options_arr`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4,3,
    [2] => 
)
```